# Java Object selection during runtime

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and am trying to overcome a problem..
I have a base class, for this example lets call it a box, and I have 3 more box classes inheriting the base box class. The reason for this is that each of these 3 boxes have different characteristics that differentiate them from each other. Lets pretend that:
Box01 can ONLY be made out of cardboard and be between 15 and 30cm long.
Box02 can ONLY be made out of aluminium and be greater than 30cm in length.
box03 can ONLY be made out of plastic and be less than 100cm in length.

In the program in question the user cannot select the type of box specifically but alternatively must supply their requirements and the program must respond saying if the product is possible. So a plastic box of 120cm is not possible, neither is a 50xm cardboard box.

My current solution is to use if statements such as:

```
if(boxType == 'cardboard' && length >= 15 && length <= 30){
    Box = new box01(boxType, length);
else if(boxType == 'aluminium' && length >= 30){
    Box = new box02(boxType, length);
}
```

I know in this simplified example it appears unnecessary to have the additional box classes but assume that in the real version that the boxes have many more unique characteristics which would reflect in the classes attributes and constructor.

Now to my question. This particular method looks ok here with only 2 tests and a few ifs but my program has considerably more attributes and many many more tests. Is there another more sophisticated way for my program to detect what kind of box my program should make besides the ifs.

Thank you for anybody who takes the time to read this, understand it and post a reply. I'm sure the solution is much simpler than I am making it out to be.

Comment: Read about **Factory Design Pattern**. Here is the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken because of you clear and simple example, but I'm not sure you need separate classes. Maybe just a factory and a set of rules, with each type of box being a different instance of a ruleset class. I'm making this into an answer so I can be clearer.

Comment: The reason for having separate classes for the boxes is for example: Box01 may or may not be able to be gift wrapped. this is specific to this box and therefor a bool would be passed to box01's constructor true/false. Box02 and Box03 should not be able to be gift wrapped at all so it doesn't make sense for them to be able to access that functionality. 

I am reading into factories currently. I can see the helpfulness of them but they do still appear to have the OF statements to define the rules? Just that it would be hidden away inside the factory instead of outside within the main class etc.

Comment: @user2981060 I don't think there is no way of avoiding `If` statements. You have to check at some point which `object` you want to create. `Factory` allows you to create an object at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I will try this method. It might be worth noting that all of the boxes have at least one characteristics that makes them unique. for example Box01 may have gift wrapping, Box02 may have additional colours and Box03 may have an option to be transparent.

Comment: Also check the answer I have added.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach for this would be to structure your application like this:

1. Use an interface or an abstract class with a basic implementation for de:

   ```
   public interface BoxType(){ //Or BoxFactory or smth like that

       public boolean isApplicable(int userInput1, String userInput2...);        /// If you have more than 1-2 user input elements, create a special object (something like `UserInput`) with the user input/requirements and just pass it.

       public Box buildBox(int userInput1, String userInput2...);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Implement each box type, defining it's applicability conditions in the `isApplicable()` Method and how to build it in the `buildBox()` method.
3. Wherever you need to check which box type is, just cycle through the existing (registered) Box types and check which one is applicable and build it.

Comment: Isn't it a `Factory` you are talking about :)

Comment: Yes, hence the BoxFactory comment :) Although I think, in this simple case, it's more easily understood if it's called Type.

Comment: Hi Cosmin SD, thank you for your replies. I will try implementing this and the above methods tonight and seeing which one works best for me. I will continue to check back here as well for any further comments.

I appreciate everyones feedback. It is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was talking about:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

enum Material {
    CARDBOARD, ALUMINIUM, PLASTIC
}

class BoxProperties {
    public Material material;
    public double length;
}

abstract interface RuleSet {
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(BoxProperties props);
}

class MyRuleSet implements RuleSet {
    private final Material material;
    private final double[] length;

    public MyRuleSet(Material mat, double minLength, double maxLength) {
        this.material = mat;
        this.length = new double[] {minLength, maxLength};
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(BoxProperties props) {
        if (props.material != material) return false;
        if (props.length < length[0] || props.length > length[1]) return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public class Box {
    private static final List<? extends RuleSet> rules;
    public final Material material;
    public final double length;

    private Box(BoxProperties props) {
        this.material = props.material;
        this.length = props.length;
    }

    public static Box createBox(BoxProperties props)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (RuleSet rs : rules) {
            if (rs.isSatisfiedBy(props)) {
                return new Box(props);
            }
        }

        //XXX This should probably be made a checked exception
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "No supported box type can fullfil the requests");
    }

    static {
        rules = Arrays.asList(
                new MyRuleSet(Material.CARDBOARD, 15, 30),
                new MyRuleSet(Material.ALUMINIUM, 30, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY),
                new MyRuleSet(Material.PLASTIC, 0, 100)
                );
    }
}
```

If you determine that you need different `Box` subclasses, then you might make `Box` abstract, and add a `createBox` method to the `RuleSet` interface, which is implemented to return a custom implementation. Also, you might need to pass some extra parameter to the Box constructor, which wasn't in the request, so it's likely that you'll want to add that.

Anyway, I repeat that I don't think you should subclass, because the client class would still see a `Box`. In order to determine if it can be wrapped, it should make something like

```
if (returnedBox instanceof MaybeWrappableBox && ((MaybeWrappableBox)returnedBox).isWrappable()) {
    ...
}
```

Then, you'd better add `isWrappable()` to all your boxes, and just return false if the box is never wrappable. That would simplify caller code, while not particularly complicating callee code.